# coldfusion arrayclear xml

Tags: xml, coldfusion, menu, coldfusion-8

I am using cfscript to delete xml nodes, however, I am having issues deleting the names dynamically.  hard coded pseudo example:

```
<cfscript>  
ArrayClear(xmlNav.myXmlDoc.UL[1].LI[2]);
</cfscript>
```

how can I set value to be deleting dynamically i.e.

```
<cfscript>  
ArrayClear("xmlNav.myXmlDoc#xmlNav.xmlPath#");
</cfscript>
```

xmlNav.xmlPath = ".UL[1].LI[2]"

thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`Evaluate()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_e-g_03.html):

```
<cfscript>  
    ArrayClear(Evaluate("xmlNav.myXmlDoc" & #xmlNav.xmlPath#));
</cfscript>
```

Comment: it did work with evaluate but is there a way to do it without using evaluate as that can be pretty slow at times.  if not I will stick with it?